# Sound muted after notification Unity project on Android

Tags: android, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have a weird problem. I develop a game **for Android** using **Unity**. I added sound to my game and play perfectly. However after a notification, all sounds **suspended** in the game.

This happens **all Android versions**. Unity version is **5.3.5f1 Personal**. Is it a bug or default behavior? I couldn't find any info or solution.

Note: I added sound to canvas but there is no code and no problem until notification. It doesn't matter what kind of notification Facebook, Message, Twitter ... sounds in the game suspended immediataly.

Answer (score 1):

> This happens all Android versions. Unity version is 5.3.5f1 Personal.
>   Is it a bug or default behavior?

Yes, it **was** a bug. I even filed for a bug report few months ago. This has been fixed in 5.4.

Comment: Thanks. I will update my Unity to latest version. Best regards.